# Python can't import object despite being present - ImportError: cannot import name methods

Tags: python

Python finds `client_accounts` but can't import methods - why? Makes no sense

```
#settings.py
method_list= []
client_accounts = {}

from settings import client_accounts
print client_accounts
from settings import method_list


{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/main_loop.py", line 63, in <module>
    from settings import method_list
ImportError: cannot import name method_list
```

Even using this did not work:

```
from settings import client_accounts, method_list
```

Comment: Try putting it in one line: `from settings import client_accounts, methods`

Comment: First off, use distinct local variables (methods is conflicting type here. )

Comment: look at the update.  Same issue unless method_list a conflicting nane

Comment: Try flipping the order in which you import `client_accounts` and `method_list` that way you will know whether the problem is in the import that comes second or something to do with the name

Comment: Is `client_clients` supposed to be `client_accounts` and just a typo in your post, or are you not printing what you think you are printing?

Comment: flipping did not work.

Comment: fixed type.  should be client_accounts

Comment: Are you importing main in settings.py? Circular imports are a problem

Comment: What error was thrown? Was it with the `method_list` or `client_accounts` when you flipped it

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: I had absolutely __NO__ problem making it work. I just copied the code you have in your question into two respective python files and it ran perfectly without any problems?!?!?

Comment: If this is the only code you have thus far, just delete both files and create new ones based on the code you have above. Editing your code again and again, you must have made some error somewhere especially with all the name changes and format changes going on.

Comment: Can you just simply show us what `settings.py` looks like?